# Ionic Vue IonDatetimeButton inside Modal bugs

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework

I have an ion-modal that renders a modal for creating for a tournament. Inside the modal, I want to have a datetime picker rendered via a `datetime-button`, so that the user can select *when* the tournament will happen. Right now if I remove the datetime picker it loads perfectly. When I add it, it loads a blank spot and the bottom of the page is below the bottom of the renderer (in this case I'm using Firefox dev tools emulating an iPhone SE) I'll include some pictures, but here's the code

And here's the console error displayed, with the relevant code:
`TypeError: baseParts is undefined`

```
    /*!
     * (C) Ionic http://ionicframework.com - MIT License
     */
    import { p as printIonWarning } from './index6.js';
    
    /**
     * Returns true if the selected day is equal to the reference day
     */
    const isSameDay = (baseParts, compareParts) => {
      return (baseParts.month === compareParts.month && baseParts.day === compareParts.day && baseParts.year === compareParts.year);
    };
    /**
     * Returns true is the selected day is before the reference day.
     */
    // This is the function that errors
    const isBefore = (baseParts, compareParts) => {
      return !!(baseParts.year < compareParts.year ||
        (baseParts.year === compareParts.year && baseParts.month < compareParts.month) ||
        (baseParts.year === compareParts.year &&
          baseParts.month === compareParts.month &&
          baseParts.day !== null &&
          baseParts.day < compareParts.day));
    };
```

```
     <ion-col class="createTournyModal__content--col" size="12">
                  <ion-item class="createTournyModal__content--item">
                    <ion-input
                      label="Tournament Name"
                      labelPlacement="floating"
                      name="name"
                      type="text"
                      autofocus
                      required
                      v-model="tournamentInputs.name"
                      class="createTournyModal__content--input"
                    />
                  </ion-item>
                  <div
                    class="createTournyModal__errors input-errors"
                    v-for="error of tournament$v.name.$errors"
                    :key="error.$uid"
                  >
                    <div class="error-msg">{{ error.$message }}</div>
                  </div>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col class="createTournyModal__content--col" size="12">
                  <ion-item class="createTournyModal__content--item">
                    <ion-input
                      label="Game"
                      labelPlacement="floating"
                      name="game"
                      type="text"
                      required
                      v-model="tournamentInputs.game"
                      class="createTournyModal__content--input"
                    />
                  </ion-item>
                  <div
                    class="createTournyModal__errors input-errors"
                    v-for="error of tournament$v.game.$errors"
                    :key="error.$uid"
                  >
                    <div class="error-msg">{{ error.$message }}</div>
                  </div>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col class="createTournyModal__content--col" size="12">
                  <ion-item class="createTournyModal__content--item">
                    <ion-datetime-button
                      datetime="tournyDatetime"
                      color="primary"
                    ></ion-datetime-button>
                  </ion-item>
    
                  <ion-popover :keep-contents-mounted="true">
                    <ion-datetime
                      id="tournyDatetime"
                      :min="now"
                      v-model="tournamentInputs.date"
                    ></ion-datetime>
                  </ion-popover>
                  <div
                    class="createTournyModal__errors input-errors"
                    v-for="error of tournament$v.date.$errors"
                    :key="error.$uid"
                  >
                    <div class="error-msg">{{ error.$message }}</div>
                  </div>
                </ion-col>
```

I included the inputs above it, the error divs are for `vuelidate` which is a validation package, the issue is it looks like this with the datetime picker [image: image with datetime button] and this is what it looks like without it [image: image without datetime button]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried moving the `<ion-popover>` out of the `<ion-grid>`? Just put it right before or after the `<ion-grid>`, or all the way to the start or end of the `<ion-content>` tag (inside it).

Comment: Tried it, still rendering the same

Answer (score 0):

Problem was default value of variable was loading into the `date` component and it was failing to reconcile the default value before the reactive variable loaded. Once I set the default to `DateTime.now().toISO()` from `luxon` it fixed the issue